# AspNetCore InvalidOperationException

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core

I am getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.INodeServices' while attempting to activate 
'ConvertHighchart.Controllers.runNodeScriptController'.
```

My controller code is this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConvertHighchart.Controllers
{
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class runNodeScriptController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly INodeServices _nodeServices;
    public runNodeScriptController(INodeServices nodeServices)
    {
        _nodeServices = nodeServices;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        var result = "";
        try
        {
            result = await _nodeServices.InvokeExportAsync<string>("test_nodejs_script",
              "generateHighChart",
              "abc");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your question? What we can see in you post, is, that your controller requires INodeServices and the error tells us that this service is not registered. We now know, that the problem is outside of your controller - typically it's not registerd in Startup.ConfigureServices.

Comment: As others mentioned, please register the service first in ConfigureServices() method. Besides, same scenario about using Node Services are discussed in this ["Obsoleting Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices and Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices"](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12890#issuecomment-518808555) on github, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error while sending POST requests to the endpoint, have you put `services.AddNodeServices();` in Startup?